# Macbook starts tor repeatedly initiate sleeping functionality too soon

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I am using MacOS 12.6.7 for my work laptop. I have the "Turn display off after" settings as 15 minutes on battery power, and 1 hour when on the power adapter.

I have noticed multiple times recently that the laptop starts to sleep extremeley quickly (less than a minute after unlocking it). I can't recreate the issue, it seems to be after I have had it on for a while though (I don't restart it every day). I have observed this issue both when on battery power, and the power adapter.

The most recent time that this happened I looked at the logs and I saw these lines over and over:

```
171728:2023-09-08 20:50:46+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171729:2023-09-08 20:50:46+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
171732:2023-09-08 20:51:26+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171733:2023-09-08 20:51:26+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
171736:2023-09-08 21:04:21+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171737:2023-09-08 21:04:21+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
171740:2023-09-08 21:06:57+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171741:2023-09-08 21:06:58+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
171744:2023-09-08 21:07:55+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171745:2023-09-08 21:07:55+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
171748:2023-09-08 21:08:28+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System is considering sleep
171749:2023-09-08 21:08:28+01 MACBOOK12 softwareupdated[508]: SUOSUPowerEventObserver: System will sleep
```

I have had a search for `SUOSUPowerEventObserver` but I couldn't find anything relevant. Does anyone have any ideas? I also notice it mentions `softwareupdated` so potentially something has updated in the background and that is causing an issue?

EDIT: I definetely think it is something to do with sleep because if I use the anphetamine app to keep it awake then it helps, but after a while of doing that the machine will still keep sleeping even with that active.